# Apache Flink - ClassNotFoundException : org.apache.flink.configuration.DescribedEnum

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

When I run my Apache Flink app via Intellij, I see this error at runtime (at compile compile-time, there are no errors):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.configuration.DescribedEnum
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

This is what I've listed in my pom.xml

```xml
<scala.version>2.12.8</scala.version>
<scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
<flink.version>1.13.5</flink.version>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I I went to the following link for the source: https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html

```bash
 wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/flink/flink-1.13.5/flink-1.13.5-src.tgz
```

The application (via Intellij) is unable to locate the `DescribedEnum` class.

I have tried adding some other dependencies, but I'm not sure which jar this is in.

Any thoughts?

Comment: One more note: you can't use Scala 2.12.8 since Flink 1.13 is tied to Scala 2.12.7.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have the basic dependency `flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}` listed in your POM. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/datastream/project-configuration/ for more details.